# Azure-LogicApp: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to deploy Azure Logic App through powershell.
I created JSON template through Visual Studio 2017. I am getting following error: Any ideas, what is going on here?

```
New-AzureRmLogicApp : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

**POWERSHELL COMMAND**

```
New-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupforutptesting123" -Name "LogicApp05" -Location "West US 2" -State "Enabled" -DefinitionFilePath "C:\Powershell\Definition03.json" -ParameterFilePath "C:\Powershell\Parameters03.json"
```

**Definition03.json**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your "C:\Powershell\Definition03.json"?

Comment: Updated the original Question

Comment: you cant change the schema of the ARM template, it should be: `"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"`. Also this is an empty ARM template so nothing will be deployed

Comment: This arm template should create blank logic app. I updated the schema with correct values. Still same error message

Comment: Could you provide the two complete json files you used?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Azure Resource Manager templates to deploy the Logic App.

1. Sign in to your Azure account.

   `Connect-AzureRmAccount`
2. Create a file of the template and you can define the Logic App name and location.

   `{
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "variables": {},
     "resources": [
       {
         "name": "LogicApp4",
         "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
         "location": "Southeast Asia",
         "tags": {
           "displayName": "LogicApp"
         },
         "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
         "properties": {
           "definition": {
             "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
             "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
             "actions": {},
             "outputs": {},
             "parameters": {},
             "triggers": {}
           },
           "parameters": {}
         }
       }
     ],
     "outputs": {}
   }`
3. Deploy to the resource group the template that defines the resources to create.

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name NorasForDeployment -ResourceGroupName NorasForTest -TemplateFile C:\Users\v-wehan\source\repos\AzureResourceGroup1\AzureResourceGroup1\LogicApp.json`

It is useful for me. For more details, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy#deploy-a-template-from-your-local-machine).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE the content in json file with

```
{"$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#", "actions": {}, "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","outputs": {},"parameters": {},"triggers": {}}
```

It will add the blank logic app. Please note, your json string in json file shouldn't have any spaces in it.